# Determine in and out momentum in shell momentum balance

Tags: fluid-mechanics, chemical-engineering

How to decide what is in momentum and what is out momentum in using shell momentum balance?
My main motive is to understand why at 25:26 in the balance equation at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sMsw8BPT578 the professor is doing $\tau_{xy}|_{x} - \tau_{xy}|_{x+\Delta x} $ and not the other way round?

Even on wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_balance it isn't written what is in and what is out. If you consider always that the ground/wall kind of releases momentum then consider this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2DHR96x21GY at 17:26 where in is taken as being released  from the center of the circular pipe and not the walls.

Comment: I 'm a 3th year chemical eng, student taking a transport phenomena course.Already done fluid mechanics and heat transfer last year.

Comment: will it depend on how the analysis is started?

Comment: If you see https://nptel.ac.in/courses/103/105/103105128/ at 22:59 , here the prof is considering `in` as the region of highest velocity which experiences least viscous force.

Comment: On the other hand in the posted question by me, the professor is taking in as where the region of min velocity is there, i.e., near the wall. The concept that I have is momentum flows from  a region of high velocity to a region of low velocity. So I 'm confused that if it is like U is the higher velocity in this case than the air-water interface like in other cases.

Comment: Sorry that's the link for lecture series, the other question is https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1063&v=2DHR96x21GY&feature=emb_logo.

Comment: Can you just tell why according to what coordinate system the professor defines the momentum balance should be like this?

Comment: Please post the whole question here. People who answer your question should not be required to watch an entire lecture video to understand what you are asking about.

Comment: Sorry, I would have written it if I was used to latex but I would write it as I will get some time. Currently busy with tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We made an assumption at the start that $ \tau_{xy} $ means momentum flows in x direction which means the "in" is in the x direction. So as long as "in" is taken in the positive x, y, z direction for appropriate coordinates the analysis w'd be right.

**Reference Book:**

Transport Phenomena

Textbook by Edwin N. Lightfoot, Robert Byron Bird, and Warren E. Stewart

Page 43
[image]